# Get custom fields data on GraphQL

Tags: field, custom-field, graphql

I have several custom fields on craftcms (cp/settings/fields), and some of them are dropdowns.

I'm trying to get this custom fields data (for example the dropdown options) on graphql, because we are using this data in another system out of CraftCMS, but I really do not have any idea on how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you can retrieve the options for a dropdown field:

```
use craft\gql\base\FieldType;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;

class DropdownField extends FieldType
{
    public static function getTypeName(): string
    {
        return 'DropdownField';
    }

    public static function getFieldDefinition(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'options',
            'type' => Type::listOf(Type::string()),
            'args' => [
                'fieldHandle' => Type::nonNull(Type::string()),
            ],
            'resolve' => function ($root, $args) {
                $fieldHandle = $args['fieldHandle'];
                $options = [];
                $field = Craft::$app->getFields()->getFieldByHandle($fieldHandle);
                if ($field) {
                    $options = $field->settings['options'];
                }
                return $options;
            },
        ];
    }
}
```

You can `register` this field by adding it to your module's `init` method:

```
use craft\gql\base\Type;

class MyModule extends \yii\base\Module
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        // Register GraphQL type for custom fields
        Event::on(
            Type::class,
            Type::EVENT_DEFINE_TYPES,
            function (DefineGqlTypesEvent $event) {
                $event->types[] = DropdownField::class;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

With this code in place, you can now `query` the options for a dropdown field using `GraphQL`, for example:

```
{
  entry(id: 123) {
    ... on MyEntryType {
      myDropdownField(options: {fieldHandle: "myDropdownField"}) {
        options
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This would return the options for the `myDropdownField` custom field on the `MyEntryType` entry with `ID` `123`.